# Set Up a running Unit Test for the following :

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm unable to set up a unit testing for the following: Having a hard time to visualize what should be Tested

Using JS/ REACT + jest/enzyme

Goal is to make sure the function gets call and what would be an output example

```
function prepadSigned(hexStr) {
  const msb = hexStr[0];
  if (msb < '0' || msb > '7') {
    return `00${hexStr}`;
  }
  return hexStr;
}
```

Comment: what framework are you using for testing?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi sorry, forgot to mention Using JS/ REACT + jest/enzyme for testing     Vsc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should be fine. I've not been able to test this myself but hopefully it points you in the right direction. I'm not certain of the use case for the function either.

```
import prepadSigned from './prepadSigned';

describe('prepadSigned', () => {
  test('should output the same input', () => {
    const str = '5';
    const actual = prepadSigned(str);
    const expected = '5';
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test('should prepend `00` to the input <', () => {
    const str = '-10';
    const actual = prepadSigned(str);
    const expected = '00-10';
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  })

  test('should prepend `00` to the input >', () => {
    const str = '9';
    const actual = prepadSigned(str);
    const expected = '009';
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  })
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error with my module - ' cannot find module '  Have 2 files: utils.js and utils.test.jsI wrote     import    utils from './src/Components/Authorization/utils';       in my utils.test.js

Comment: Make sure you're exporting the method you want to test.

`export function foo() {};`

`import { foo } from './utils`

Comment: thank you -  ran the code now and it fail : following error :  for each test situation :                                                                                          ● prepadSigned › should output the same input

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "5"
    Received:
      undefined

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.

Comment: You should use numbers. Change the tests to use number types and then change your method until the tests pass.

Comment: I did some change and included 2 const - str and str2 of different values. It passed the test. But I don't think I changed it correctly

Comment: describe('prepadSigned', () => {
  test('should output the same input', () => {
    const str = '5';
    const actual = prepadSigned(str);
    const str2 = '0';
    const expected = prepadSigned(str2)
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  })
});

Comment: If the strings are the same or if they are different= test pass anyway. Not sure if its correct

Comment: I'll setup this up in a proper environment and test it. Will update my answer if i need to. Perhaps changing to integers will be better as stated. :)

Comment: I'm still having the same errors . Were you able to figure out ?

Comment: missing :  export  in front of function prepadSigned(hexStr)